# RavenDB replication

Tags: c#, replication, ravendb

I have two DB on different ports 8080 and 8081 both are configured to replicate to each other. When I was testing this mecanism with all servers turned off, I noticed that just after the Inicialization of DocumentStores they both have ReplicationDestinations even there was no possible way for program to get this data... I noticed also that it only works if ports are 8080 and 8081 (It didn't work for a pair 8085 and 8083)

Can someone tell me, how it is possible that DocumentStore had information about replication even though it didn't have the possibility to know anything about databases?

Comment: Your question make no sense. What errors are you getting?

Comment: @AyendeRahien 
I don't get any errors. :) But this interests me because it looks like DocumentStore got some data from void.
I'm just interested how RavenDB can obtain such information without working servers.